# Powershell how to abort/exit from the input command (ctrl+C UNIX equivalent)?

Tags: powershell, command, keyboard-shortcuts

This is a very basic question, but I could not find the answer on the internet or on StackOverflow.

**Problem description and example:**

Inputting 'cd..' into the PowerShell console takes me onto a new line with this '~>' waiting for more input and I cant get out of it again.

How can I abort this command? I would like to get back to '~\Documents>'. In UNIX bash I would hit **ctrl+c.**

What is the equivalent to Ctrl+c in PowerShell?

Example PowerShell console:

```
~\Documents> cd..
~>
~> ^X$
$ : The term '$' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ $
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried exit, Ctrl+c, Ctrl+X, Ctrl+Shift+c and many others... =(

Comment: Ehhh, `~` is the same as `$home` - try `cd ..` again and see what happens :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I abort this command?

It's also `ctrl-c` in powershell to abort

It looks like you're not actually getting stuck in line continuation though, it seems to actually be moving up a folder. Did you try running any normal commands when it shows you `~>`?

As Mathias said, `~` can be used to represent `$home`.

Comment: Ha, that's it. I was just misled by the representation.

Comment: PS is definitely quirky with some of that stuff ;), glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you! Unbelievable I trapped myself, while not being in a trap. LOL.